# Derivative of $ f:\mathbb{R}^{n,n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n,n}, A\mapsto A^3 $ with chain an product rule

Tags: real-analysis

I'm trying to calculate the derivative of $ f:\mathbb{R}^{n,n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n,n}, A\mapsto A^3 $ with chain an product rule.

I consider the functions:
$$ \mu: \mathbb{R}^{n,n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n,n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n,n} \to \mathbb{R}^{n,n}, (A,B,C)\mapsto A\cdot B\cdot C\\g:\mathbb{R}^{n,n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n,n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n,n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n,n}, X\mapsto (X,X,X) $$
such that $ f=\mu \circ g: \mathbb{R}^{n,n}\to \mathbb{R}^{n,n}, M\mapsto M\cdot M\cdot M=M^3 $.
So I want to get the derivative $ Df(A)=D(\mu \circ g)(A) $. But I have to show that g is differentiable at $A$ (which I was able to do because it is just a linear function) and $ \mu $ is differentiable at $ g(A) $ and I don't know how to do that.

If I have this than I can easily apply the chain and product rule.

Comment: Have you tried this approach for $A^2$ instead of $A^3$?

Comment: No. How can help this?

Comment: Trying a similar but simpler problem often helped me to move forward. And once you know how to differentiate products of 2 matrices you can apply this to $A^2\cdot A$.

Comment: But then I get the same problem and I don't see how to solve this. If only have $ f(A)=A $ then $ f $ is linear and get $ Df(A)=f $.

Answer (score 0):

This is slightly sloppy but if we use $\delta X$ for the linear approximation of small changes we get this:

$$ \delta (A\cdot B) = \delta A \cdot B + A \cdot \delta B$$
$$ \delta (A^2) = \delta A \cdot A + A \cdot \delta A$$
$$ \delta (A^3) = \delta (A^2 \cdot A) = \delta (A^2)\cdot A + A^2\cdot \delta A$$
$$
= \left( \delta A \cdot A + A \cdot \delta A \right)\cdot A + A^2 \cdot\delta A
$$
$$
= \delta A \cdot A^2 + A \cdot \delta A\cdot A + A^2 \cdot\delta A
$$

An alternative way is to use:

$$\delta (A\cdot B\cdot C) = 
\delta A\cdot B\cdot C + A\cdot \delta B\cdot C + A\cdot B\cdot\delta C$$